# Unable to create a side navigation bar using materialize css?

Tags: materialize

I am trying to create a side navigation bar using MaterializeCSS. I have following code. But when I try to run it in browser it does not show anything. It shows only blank page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Side Navigation Bar</title>

    <!-- Compiled and minified jQuery -->
    <script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">
/script>

    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" 
rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/
css/materialize.min.css">

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/
js/materialize.min.js"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
           $('.collapsible').collapsible();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a href="#!">First Sidebar Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">Second Sidebar Link</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav">
            <li><a href="#!">First Sidebar Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">Second Sidebar Link</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse"><i 
    class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i></a>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

please suggest me if any bug is there.

Answer (score 1):

There is a "bug" in your code - on 7th line your script (the one importing jQuery) is being closed incorrectly - you have `/script>` instead of `</script>`

In addition, you are using outdated method to put material icons in i tags - you should have `<i class="material-icons">menu</i>` instead of `<i ="mdi-navigation-menu"></i>`. Or if you prefer the 'old' way, I guess you will have to find that library and upload into your project as if I remember this right, that method is no longer officially supported.

Here is my edition of your code that works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Side Navigation Bar</title>

    <!-- Compiled and minified jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
           $('.collapsible').collapsible();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
    <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav">
        <li><a href="#!">First Sidebar Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">Second Sidebar Link</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your version of the code. It shows a nav-bar on top of the page. But I don't see the navigation icon and not able to open side navigation bar.

Comment: Because it is for mobile menu. Resize your browser to a mobile size and you will see it

Comment: Can I make this icon visible in big screen?

Comment: Yes you can, but that would duplicate your menu - you already have those links in top navbar. So it's deliberately hidden so that a visitor does not get two similar menus at the same time. I suggest you decide what kind of menu you need and look into materialize documentation, they have covered most pf the stuff pretty well

Comment: Actually I want side nav bar only. I don't want top bar. But when tried it, it didn't work. Any way, thanks for your help.

Comment: But judging from your comment on the other answer, you don't need the nav at all so I hope this will be the final update of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try following as your `nav` content

```
<nav>
        <div class="nav-wrapper container">
            <a id="logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo text-darken-1">Logo</a>

            <div class="container">
                <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse top-nav full hide-on-large-only black-text"><i
                        class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav fixed center-align">
            <li><a href="#!">First Sidebar Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">Second Sidebar Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">First Sidebar Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">Second Sidebar Link</a></li>
        </ul>        
</nav>
```

And add following in your `CSS` (Use header, main, footer in your `body` as an HTML-5 standard):

```
header, main, footer {
    padding-left: 240px;
}
```

Comment: This code works. It shows the side-nav panel. But it is opened already. I want to see the navigation icon and clicking on it should open it.

Comment: The navigation icon will show on mobile size screen. Try minimizing your browser.